# Some questions related to Fraud detection demo from Flink DataStream API

Tags: apache-flink

The example is very useful at first,it illustrates how keyedProcessFunction is working in Flink
there is something worth noticing, it suddenly came to me...
It is from **Fraud Detector v2: State + Time** part
It is reasonable to set a timer here, regarding the real application requirement part

```
override def onTimer(
    timestamp: Long,
    ctx: KeyedProcessFunction[Long, Transaction, Alert]#OnTimerContext,
    out: Collector[Alert]): Unit = {
  // remove flag after 1 minute
  timerState.clear()
  flagState.clear()
}
```

Here is the problem:

The TimeCharacteristic IS ProcessingTime which is determined by the system clock of the running machine, according to ProcessingTime property, the watermark will NOT be changed overtime, so that means onTimer will never be called, unless the TimeCharacteristic changes to eventTime

According the flink website:
An hourly processing time window will include all records that arrived at a specific operator between the times when the system clock indicated the full hour. For example, if an application begins running at 9:15am, the first hourly processing time window will include events processed between 9:15am and 10:00am, the next window will include events processed between 10:00am and 11:00am, and so on.
If the watermark doesn't change over time, will the window function be triggered? because the condition for a window to be triggered is when the watermark enters the end time of a window

I'm wondering the condition where the window is triggered or not doesn't depend on watermark in priocessingTime, even though the official website doesn't mention that at all, it will be based on the processing time to trigger the window

Hope someone can spend a little time on this,many thx!

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to clarify a few things:

Flink provides two kinds of timers: *event time* timers, and *processing time* timers. An event time timer is triggered by the arrival of a watermark equal to or greater than the timer's timestamp, and a processing time timer is triggered by the system clock reaching the timer's timestamp.

Watermarks are only relevant when doing event time processing, and only purpose they serve is to trigger event time timers. They play no role at all in applications like the one in this [DataStream API Code Walkthrough](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/getting-started/walkthroughs/datastream_api.html#final-application) that you have referred to. If this application used event time timers, either directly, or indirectly (by using event time windows, or through one of the higher level APIs like SQL or CEP), then it would need watermarks. But since it only uses processing time timers, it has no use for watermarks.

BTW, this fraud detection example isn't using Flink's Window API, because Flink's windowing mechanism isn't a good fit for this application's requirements. Here we are trying to a match a pattern to a sequence of events within a specific timeframe -- so we want a different kind of "window" that begins at the moment of a special triggering event (a small transaction, in this case), rather than a `TimeWindow` (like those provided by Flink's Window API) that is aligned to the clock (i.e., 10:00am to 10:01am).

Comment: Thx a lot, David,your response is of great value, i now understand it deeper, thx for clarifying that!